# Текстовый курсор съезжает в начало строки при каждом заполнении поля

Tags: текст, android-spinner

Речь не про курсор базы данных, а про обычный текстовый курсор при наборе текста.
У меня в поле ввода данные входят через выборку из массива spinner. После каждого такого выбора, курсор, вместо того чтобы остаться в конце набора, съезжает в самое начало, и его надо вручную переводить на конец строки.
Что за поведение такое? Можно ли это отменить?